# Draw lines in layout using Listbox WPF

Tags: wpf, listbox, line

I need to draw lines in the container using ListBox control of WPF. The reason to use Listbox control being that I have a collection of objects which are basically custom Line objects exposing x1,y1 and x2,y2 points. So, once the line is drawn that would be added to the collection such that it can be displayed at the same time.

The code which I'm using to draw lines in listbox is :

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="4" Name="listBoxLines" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=RadioCaliperOn, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}"  Style="{x:Null}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Calipers}" >
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></Canvas>
                            <!--<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></Grid>-->
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

                    <ListBox.Resources>

                        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Style.Resources>
                                <!-- Background of selected item when focussed -->
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
                                <!-- Background of selected item when not focussed -->
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
                            </Style.Resources>
                            <Style.Setters>
                                <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Brush_CZBscanImagePinkBorder}"/>-->
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
                                <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
                            </Style.Setters>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BrushTransparent}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource BrushTransparent}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                        <Style TargetType="ListBox">
                            <Style.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="ListBox.BorderThickness" Value="0"></Setter>
                            </Style.Setters>
                        </Style>
                        <Style TargetType="ScrollViewer">
                            <Style.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"></Setter>
                                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"></Setter>
                            </Style.Setters>
                        </Style>
                    </ListBox.Resources>


                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Line Cursor="Hand" X1="{Binding Converter={StaticResource caliperToLineConverter}, ConverterParameter=X1}" Y1="{Binding Converter={StaticResource caliperToLineConverter}, ConverterParameter=Y1}" X2="{Binding Converter={StaticResource caliperToLineConverter}, ConverterParameter=X2}" Y2="{Binding Converter={StaticResource caliperToLineConverter}, ConverterParameter=Y2}" Stroke="{Binding Converter={StaticResource selectedCalliperColorConverter},RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" StrokeThickness="2" Height="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,0" Stretch="Fill"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                </ListBox>
```

The problem which I'm facing is that in case if there are any existing lines in the collection, then when I just mouse click my container to draw a line, the existing item of listbox gets selected and in turn I'm not able to draw any line. Please let me know the exact way or the approach that I can easily draw the lines with each line being an item of listbox. Thanks.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are doing, can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms611045.aspx) instead of ListBox and throw away the whole `<ListBox.Resources>` stuff. All you need should be

```
<ItemsControl ...>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Line ... />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```